# Check for updates in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to update **ADT plugin** from 20.0.3 to 22.6.2, I am using Eclipse juno, My eclipse takes almost 8 hours from the morning, Still it trying to **Contacting Software Sites** , I don't know what have to do now, Any help will be highly appreciable.

**Note:** Already I have unchecked all other software sites expect **https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/**

Comment: I can guess that either your hardware is really slow or your network connection is down. It takes me 10 minutes to upgrade the whole thing... including "check for updates".

Comment: Have you check your proxy setting? Maybe if your are in a company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try connecting to the site using your web browser.

- If the browser succeeds and Eclipse fails, then the problem is most likely the Eclipse proxy settings.
- If the browser also fails to access the site, then it is time to talk to your local network people ...

---

FWIW, I can connect to that site using a browser.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have checked the proxy in eclipse, It is same as chrome. The link works in chrome. So I tried to download new eclipse-standard-kepler-sr2-win32, can I use it for android development?

Comment: I don't see why not.  Try it and see.  (But I'd advise making a copy of your existing Eclipse install and your workspaces first ...)